# split a vector and fill every other element in order to have specific length

Tags: r

I have a vector which I split into some parts, I compute the mean of every part and then I want to have a vector with the original length which will contain the mean values and between them fill with NA.

```
vec <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000)
s <- 2

parts <- split(vec, rep(1:s, ceiling(length(vec) / s),
              length.out = length(vec)))

the_mean <- lapply(parts, mean)
res <- unlist(the_mean)

res <- replace(NA * s, seq(from = 1 , to = length(vec), length = length(res)), res)
res
```

The result I receive now is:

`4000 NA NA NA NA NA NA 5000`

I want to receive :

`4000 NA NA 5000 NA NA NA NA`

because the splitting is done by `s <-2`, so I have the first mean (4000) and after 2 values , I must have the second mean (5000). The rest vector should be filled with NA. The reason is that I want the result vector to have the same length as the initial (vec).

If for example, `s = 3`, then the result should be:

`4000 NA NA NA 5000 NA NA 4500` .

Note, that between 5000 and 4500 we have 2 NA and not 3 since the vector size is 8.

Comment: What is the logic of splitting the vector `vec` ? How do you define each "part" ?

Comment: @RonakShah: For example, I will have a number of values per minute and I want to find the mean by hour (so s =60) . But I want to return a vector with the original length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it :

```
apply_fun <- function(vec, s) {
   #Initialize the vector with NA
   ans <- rep(NA, length(vec))
   #Create groups to calculate mean
   groups <- rep(1:s, ceiling(length(vec) / s),length.out = length(vec))
   #Create indices to place mean of each group
   vals <- pmin(seq(1, by = s + 1, length.out = s), length(vec))
   #Assign mean values at those indices
   ans[vals] <- tapply(vec, groups, mean)
   #Return the final answer
   return(ans)
}

apply_fun(vec, 2)
#[1] 4000   NA   NA 5000   NA   NA   NA   NA

apply_fun(vec, 3)
#[1] 4000   NA   NA   NA 5000   NA   NA 4500
```

Comment: Hi, I think we have a problem!1) I think `vals` should be `vals <- pmin(seq(1, by = s , length.out = length(vec)), length(vec))` (change `length.out` to have vec  length, because If you try `vec<- 1:200, s<-10`, it will give 10 indices and the result will have 10 values and the rest nans.  2) If you use `s<- 60, vec<- 1:20000` , then (by applying the correction above) you will receive a vector with full values and nans as intended, but it will give (sometimes!) a warning: `In result[idxs] <- tapply(FlowVol, groups, mean) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`)

Comment: I found that if you use `vec=20000, s=60`, it gives you the warning, but if you use `vec=27000, s=60`, it does not! (again, use `lenght.out=length(vec)` in the `pmin`

Comment: I see. I don't completely understand what you are trying to say at the moment though.